# What is the best way to create a custom cookie using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set personalized cookies in Google Tag Manager for the first time. Searching the web, I have found different Javascript functions and I was wondering which one I should use, as I am not a developer and I don't really know how "good code" looks like :)

The first function is the following :

```
<script>
  function createCookie(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; domain=insérernomdedomaineici";
  }

  createCookie("lead_magnet_getresponse_devis","devis",60);
</script>
```

The second one is this one :

```
<script>

 var cookieName = "visitorFromAdwords"; // Name of your cookie
 var cookieValue = "true"; // Value of your cookie
 var expirationTime = 2592000; // One month in seconds
 expirationTime = expirationTime * 1000; // Converts expirationtime to milliseconds
 var date = new Date(); 
 var dateTimeNow = date.getTime(); 

 date.setTime(dateTimeNow + expirationTime); // Sets expiration time (Time now + one month)
 var date = date.toUTCString(); // Converts milliseconds to UTC time string
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+cookieValue+"; expires="+date+"; path=/; domain=." + location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, ""); // Sets cookie for all subdomains

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way right now is to create a [custom template](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/) and use the [setCookie API](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#setcookie). Not only does this provide "officially sanctioned" function to create a cookie, it also runs what Google calls "sandboxed Javascript", which nips potential security problems with custom javascript functions ins the bud (which makes working with custom templates sometimes a pain in the backside, but the added security and convenience of being able to create a GUI for your setCookie tag should be worth it).

Comment: thank you for the answer ! I'm going to look into it.

Comment: @monicab, you can also look at the community template gallery, there already is a cookie template that might work for you: https://tagmanager.google.com/gallery/#/owners/gtm-templates-anto-hed/templates/cookie-creator